# Select child of sibling element

Tags: selenium, xpath, ancestor

I have the following HTML DOM. My goal is to get the "Error" text.

```
<div class = "row">
   <div class ="col-sm-4">
      <input id = "firstName" type = "text"> John
      <div class = "mh-15">
         <div class = "text-danger">Error</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As class = "text-danger" is repeated numerous times, my goal is to get to the "Error" text by starting from id = "firstName" and going down the way by using something like an xpath ancestor. How should i do that? Thanks!

Comment: is the `input` node a sibling of `<div class = "mh-15">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath :

```
//input[@id='firstName']/following-sibling::div[2]
```

Note that `<div class = "mh-15">` should be sibling of input box.

Comment: Just and update: more safe locator: //input[@id='firstName']/following-sibling::*//div[@class='text-danger']

Comment: @Infern0 : text-danger class is changing , as OP stated. I don't think so that will be good choice.

Comment: I have read the statement: 'As class = "text-danger" is repeated numerous times', so my advice is relevant.

Comment: This XPath will not work as target `div` is not *second sibling `div`*, but *child of first sibling `div`*. Check @ewwink answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. All of you provided very helpful answers. What worked for me was @infern0's locator, even though all of them were quite similar to each other.

Comment: @Andersson : in that case it will differ slightly `following-sibling::div/child::div`

Answer (score 2):

`ancestor` is for selecting parent element, the `class="text-danger"` is after the element of `id="firstName"` you have to  select it with `following` or `following-sibling`

```
//input[@id="firstName"]/following-sibling::div/div
# or
//input[@id="firstName"]/following::div/div
```